# ngx-translate fails to resolve translations when running Jasmine/Karma tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, ngx-translate

I have a simple Angular component with translatable text content, which I want to test. Unfortunately, the text content of my component is always empty when running my Jasmine/Karma tests.

However, the translated text is displayed when running the application itself and I can even receive the translation directly from `TranslateService` in a separate Jasmine test.

How can I fix displaying the translated text in my HTML template for Jasmine/Karma?

My component "foo.component.ts":

```js
@Component({selector: 'app-foo', template: `<p>{{ 'hello' | translate }}</p>`})
export class FooComponent {
}
```

My translation file "assets/i18n/en.json":

```json
{
  "hello": "Hello World!"
}
```

My test "foo.component.spec.ts":

```js
const createTranslateHttpLoader = (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http);

describe('FooComponent', () => {
  let component: FooComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FooComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: createTranslateHttpLoader, deps: [HttpClient]},
          defaultLanguage: 'en'
        })
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should display greeting', () => { // <= fails
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.textContent).toBe('Hello World!');
  });

  it('has greeting translation', async () => { // <= works
    const translation = await TestBed.inject(TranslateService).get('hello').toPromise();
    expect(translation).toBe('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

I'm using Angular 11.0.1 and ngx-translate 13.0.0.

Comment: Martin, can you take a look at the way I wrote one unit test for one of the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112046/ngx-translate-instant-function-is-not-a-function-thrown-unit-testing/57132018#57132018 . Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Hi Shashank Vivek, I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-testing as testing dependency now, which does more or less the same as your code example in your answer. It seems that mocking translation loading is the best solution.

Comment: ok, just let me know (with code snippet) if you get stuck somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it might not be necessary to test against actual i18n files. Verifying that we are using correct translation key (in your case `'hello'`) should be enough.

We can start by creating fake `TranslateLoader` like this:

```
class FakeTranslateLoader extends TranslateLoader {
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of({
      "hello": "Hello World!"
    });
  }
}
```

Then, import it into `foo.component.spec.ts`:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FooComponent],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: FakeTranslateLoader
          }
        })
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should display greeting', () => {
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.textContent).toBe('Hello World!');
  });
```